# What is tf FlatMapDataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I cannot find anything about this type of tensorflow dataset: FlatMapDataset.

I came over it by using Hugginface traformer library. The glue_convert_examples_to_features functions returns it.

What is it? And what do I do with it?